# Baffling behavior from QFontDatabase

Tags: python, qt, fonts, pyside, qtgui

I am trying to load a font into my application. Logically, I want to load more than one font weight, but that's where the problem arises.

I have two font files, "PFD-Black.ttf" and "PFD-Regular.ttf". I want to use them both, so I load them both using this code:

```
fontid_regular = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("PFD-Regular.ttf")
fontid_black = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("PFD-Black.ttf")
```

I then get the family name, like so:

```
familyname = fontdb.applicationFontFamilies(fontid_black)[0]
```

Note that I have tried using `fontid_regular` as well but to no avail. Then I attempt to use the font for a QLabel:

```
lab = QLabel("My Font Window")
font = QFont(familyname)
lab.setFont(font)
lab.show()
```

That is the extent of my code, other than the boilerplate imports and QApplication.exec_() call.

This does not work (which may be obvious since I'm asking a question on SO about it), the label shows up in the default font.

[image: This is when is doesn't work]

The baffling part about my problem, is that when I comment out the line `fontid_regular = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("PFD-Regular.ttf")` the bold font shows.

[image: This is when it kind of works]

This is some level of workingness (for lack of a better word), but I am not able to use the regular weight font. It should also be noted that commenting out the line where I load "PFD-Black.ttf" does not fix the issue.

Note that I *have* seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335240/qt-font-resources-work-for-normal-weight-fail-for-bold), but no matter what mutations I perform on my code, I cannot make that solution work for me, so please don't mark this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: What is the value of `applicationFontFamilies` for both fonts? I suspect they are the same, so when you load both fonts, the first one is found by the family name, and when you didn't load the first font, the second one shows up. It could explain why commenting `fontid_regular` out changes the behavior. Try to use `font.setBold(true)` to use the second font while loading both fonts.

Comment: Its a good idea, but while I have both loaded, the default Helvetica or whatever it is is used as the font for the QLabel, not the lighter weight custom font.

Comment: And I have tried various combinations of `setBold` and commenting out lines, none of which worked.

Comment: Is it happening on Mac? Which version of it?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov is right here, I think based on the internal code `families.append(QCFString(CTFontCopyFamilyName(font)));`. If `font = QFont(familyname); font.setBold(true);` does not work, file a bugreport on the following tracker: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/

Comment: @ekhumoro: works for me. What do you mean by "borked"?

Comment: @ekhumoro: what I wrote was, "file a bugreport on the following tracker: bugreports.qt-project.org". Why would you have a bug number for a bug that is about to be filed? :D

Comment: @LaszloPapp. Damn! Sorry, I must be hallucinating - I somehow read "like this bugreport..."

Comment: Yes it is on a mac, version 10.8.4

Comment: @KFox. What does `QFontDatabase().styles(fontname)` give you for each font? And what are the actual names (not filenames) of the fonts? Have tried loading the fonts using [QFontDatabase.font](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html#font)?

Comment: When both fonts are being loaded, `QFontDatabase().styles(fontname)`, returns `[u'Normal', u'Bold']`, as I would expect. The names of both fonts are the same, `'Playfair Display'`. I had not thought of `QFontDatabase.font()`, but trying it with several combinations of other solutions all failed.

Comment: @KFox. Have you tried the solution in the other question you linked to using the same "Avenir" font? If that works, then it would seem that the issue is finding the equivalent munged names for your "Playfair Display" font.

Comment: The "Avenir" font cost an amount of money I was not willing to pay, so I tried my code with several different fonts from Google Fonts, which worked much better. Different fonts needed different configurations though (some loaded different weights as different families, others loaded them all as one), do you know any way around that?

Comment: No, sorry. So are you saying that the problem is just with this specific "Playfair Display" font?

Comment: Yes, the issue was with the font I suppose, thankyou for all your help!

Comment: Hmm, that was also one option when I discussed this with one of the developers behind, but I thought that would be the last guess since this kind of thing is unforunate. Glad you figured out. :)

Comment: Is this behavior worthy of a bug report? I would guess not since it was fixed by using a different font.

Comment: Bugreport against what? Qt cannot be blamed for you having bad fonts. :D

Comment: Thats what I assumed but I just wanted to make sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved in the comments above: it turned out that there was a problem with the font I was using.